# Hide silverlight controls and other controls Should shift up automatically

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight form (xaml) on which there are multiple control like lable , textboxes and grid, in some scenario i have to hide some controls, that i am doing by

```
ctrl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

whic hides the control from the form but space consumed by the control is not shrinked. What I want is when those controls are hide then other control of the form will shift up automatically.

```
<controls:ChildWindow x:Class="IPVWorkbench.Views.CommentsDialog"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
           xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
           xmlns:telerikGrid="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView"  
           xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"  
           xmlns:ipvmodel="clr-namespace:IPVWorkbench.Models"
           Width="557" Height="800" 
           Title="Comments" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="104" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="28" />
            <RowDefinition Height="72" />
            <RowDefinition Height="72" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="72" />
            <RowDefinition Height="72" />
            <RowDefinition Height="23" />
            <RowDefinition Height="32" />
            <RowDefinition Height="21*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Click="CancelButton_Click" Width="75" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,5,3" Grid.Row="9" TabIndex="8" />
        <Button x:Name="OKButton" Content="OK" Click="OKButton_Click" Width="75" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="373,6,0,3" Grid.Row="9" TabIndex="7" />
        <TextBox Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" Margin="34,0,0,11" Name="txtComments" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="454" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TabIndex="1" />
        <sdk:Label Height="28" Content="Comments:" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,0,0,0" Name="commentsLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <sdk:Label Height="17" Content="Trader Comments:" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,4,0,0" Name="traderCommentsLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="7" Margin="34,22,0,0" Name="traderCommentsTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="454" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TabIndex="5" />
        <TextBlock Height="78" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,12,0,0" Name="messageTextBox" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="454" />
        <CheckBox Content="Is Trader Review Complete?" Height="16" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,4,0,0" Name="isTraderReviewCompleteCheckBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="6" />
        <TextBox Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="6" Margin="34,24,0,0" Name="escalationCommentsTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="454" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TabIndex="4" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Escalation Comments:" Height="16" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,4,0,0" Name="escalationCommentsLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="5" Margin="34,22,0,0" Name="escalationReasonComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="454" ItemsSource="{Binding EscalationEnum}" TabIndex="3" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Escalation Reason:" Height="23" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,4,0,0" Name="escalationReasonLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <TextBox Height="48" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="4" Margin="34,17,0,0" Name="txtUserNotes" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="454" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TabIndex="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <sdk:Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="4" Margin="34,0,0,0" Name="userNotesLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" Content="User Notes:" />
        <!--START: Added by Rohit Vyas for HPQC#1967-->
        <sdk:Label Content="Are you sure you want to send these positions for approval?" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,2,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Name="lblSure" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="454" />
        <Grid x:Name="PositionNotTaken" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <sdk:Label Content="Positions That are not eligible:" Height="19" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,2,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Name="lblpositionsNotValid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="285" />
        <telerikGrid:RadGridView x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="EditableGV" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="34,29,25,45" Height="141">


        </telerikGrid:RadGridView>
        </Grid>
        <!--END: Added by Rohit Vyas for HPQC#1967-->
    </Grid>
</controls:ChildWindow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, i be able to do the above by putting all my controls those i am going to hide inside a StackPanel. If you set the visibility of a control to Collapsed that is inside StackPanel then this panel automatically shifts the elements below to top.